# Can't access application running in host from a pod in kubernetes running using minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm having an issue whereby I can't access an app running on host machine, from an app running in a Kubernetes Pod in Minikube.

In this case, the app running on the host machine is a Postgre DB, and the app running in the pod is psql, well actually it's a dotnet core application developed by me, but I'm using psql here for simulation purposes.

```
Operating System   : Windows 10 Pro
Minikube version   : 0.30.0
Kubernetes version : 1.11.0
VM driver          : HyperV
```

My host network looks like this:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7970:dbd6:f9ab:b9b0%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Primary Virtual Switch):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.33
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::241f:1091:ab14:ff1c%24
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.251.177
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I've chosen `Default Switch` as the `Virtual Switch` for the minikube VM in the HyperV settings. I've tried using the `Primary Virtual Switch` but it's not working also.

`Default Switch` is an Internal network Connection type.

`Primary Virtual Switch` is an External network Connection type.

The Minikube network looks like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul                                                                                                                                                             t qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group defa                                                                                                                                                             ult qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:fb:b1:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.251.182/28 brd 172.24.251.191 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86321sec preferred_lft 86321sec
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fefb:b129/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP gr                                                                                                                                                             oup default
    link/ether 02:42:e7:f1:e1:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:e7ff:fef1:e1ad/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth61a3792@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue mas                                                                                                                                                             ter docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 52:fb:43:92:d0:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::50fb:43ff:fe92:d0f1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

<I omitted the remaining veth interfaces>
```

I am sure that the Postgre DB is accessible from anywhere, because when I tried to access it from an application running in a docker container deployed in a Docker Swarm it's able to connect successfully, and also I've set the pg_hba.conf to this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Some other things that I tried to find the root cause of the issue

```
kubectl run -i --tty myalpine --image=alpine -- sh

/ # ping 172.24.251.177
PING 172.24.251.177 (172.24.251.177): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.24.251.177: seq=0 ttl=127 time=0.351 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.251.177: seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.961 ms

/ # traceroute 172.24.251.177
traceroute to 172.24.251.177 (172.24.251.177), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)  0.006 ms  0.006 ms  0.003 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *

/ # psql -h 172.24.251.177 -U myuser -d mydb
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on host "172.24.251.177" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any chance some of you guys experienced this issue also? or is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) on minikube so the psql application is able to access the PostGreDb on your host machine.

Comment: Try `psql -h http://172.24.251.177:5432 -U myuser -d mydb`

Comment: @peter, Have you checked `listen_addresses` parameter in `postgresql.conf` file?